# Test Spring batch with @JpaDataTest

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-test

I'm using spring batch 4.0 and i'm trying to test my batch.
I would use embedded database h2 with @JpaDataTest but it doesn't work.
When i add this annotation i got error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).

@Transaction(propagation=Propagation.NEW_REQUIRED) on the @Test dosen't work.

I tried to copy every annotations from @JpaDataTest and remove @Transaction

```
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@AutoConfigureCache
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@ImportAutoConfiguration
```

But when i'm doing this, i'm lossing the EntityManager...

Someone already find a solution ?

Comment: What happens if you annotate your `@DataJpaTest` (assuming you mean that instead of `@JpaDataTest`) class with `@Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)`?

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).

This error happens when you try to run Spring Batch code (which drives a transaction) in an outer transactional context (the test in your example).

Instead of adding `@Transaction(propagation=Propagation.NEW_REQUIRED)` on the test, you should try to deactivate transactions instead, letting Spring Batch drive the transaction. For example, using:

```
@Transaction(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

> I tried to copy every annotations from @JpaDataTest and remove @Transaction [...] But when i'm doing this, i'm lossing the EntityManager...

You need to make sure that Spring Batch uses the transaction manager you want (I guess a `JpaTransactionManager` in your case) to drive its transactions. To do that, you need to define a bean of type `BatchConfigurer` in your batch configuration and override `getTransactionManager`. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                    return new MyTransactionManager();
            }
    };
}
```

You can find more details in the [Java Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) section of the reference documentation.

Hope this helps.